Losing pages information when execute update.php in mediawiki 1.30.x
Basically, in version 1.28, I have some pages in a wiki where we have a kind of collapsable menu. When update to 1.30 or 1.32, during the upgrading process, after executing 'update.php' script, every page who has this collapsible menu, loss the information and appends information of other page. Any other with this same issue?
Already restored database, trying to find if this collapsible menu doesn't exists anymore (I believe this, but now since this point I don't know exactly how I can solve it)
